# Trying to passthru my RTX 2080 ti to a Windows 7 x64 bit vm using virt-manager on Ubuntu 21.10 : it gives error 12

Tags: linux, windows-7, virtualization, nvidia-geforce, qemu

I would like to virtualize Windows 7 x64 bit passing through my graphic card (rtx 2080 ti) with qemu-kvm on Ubuntu 21.10. It's failing for me,so I'm trying to understand what's wrong. After several modifications to the xml code of libvirt suggested by a very nice reddit user,that you can read here :

https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/r81616/how_to_passthru_my_rtx_2080_ti_to_a_windows_vm/

I ended up with this configuration :

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/f2MCTf52xg/

Unfortunately in UEFI mode windows 7 freezes on its logo,even if it able to connect to the net. While in BIOS mode my monitor does not turn on at all.

I've installed the ssh server inside windows 7 and from Linux I tried to connect to that server and I've issued the following command :

```
mario@MARIETTO-PC C:\Users\mario>wmic path win32_videocontroller get configmanagererrorcode
ConfigManagerErrorCode
0
12
```

because I wanted to check the status of my graphic card inside windows 7. I mean,which error it shows. As u can see it seems to be 12. So,it seems that my rtx 2080 ti even without the default graphic adapter (-vga none),it does not work,reporting error 12.

**Error 12 :
The “This device cannot find enough free that it can use (Code 12)” problem is displayed within the device’s properties windows in the Device status box. That error is usually a hardware conflict which arises when two devices are assigned the same I/O port but there are other culprits as well.**

At beginning I've thought that the error 12 was caused by the presence of the default graphic display adapter,but it seems that the cause is another one,because it is still present if I use "-vga none".

I've googled a little bit and maybe I found the fix for this error in this site :

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414098

where he says :

My system has a very similar setup that was giving me the same code 12 error. I have been able to able to get it working with the following setting in virt-manager:
CPUs -> Model -> Haswell-noTSX-IBRS
Using the "Copy host CPU configuration" appeared to give me issues.

even if I'm not sure that it will fix the error,I tried,but another error happened :

[image: pic]

Comment: Dumb question: Do you have two graphics cards? If not then obviously you can't do this.

Comment: yes. The first one is : 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (rev 02),but I haven't passed it through inside the VM.

Answer (score 1):

It's UEFI or bust, I'm afraid. BIOS with VGA passthrough never work properly. You will probably need a different, more up to date OVMF UEFI firmware to make it work, and you will probably have to edit the XML definition of the VM because virt-manager won't get you all the way there. Here is a summary of my experience when putting together the same kind of [virtual gaming setup with GPU passthrough](https://altechnative.net/virtually-gaming-part-2-evolution-consolidation-and-move-to-kvm/).

One obvious problem with your VM definition is that you are using q35 emulation. That still doesn't work for PCI passthrough, you need to use 440fx.

Comment: but I'm using the UEFI bootloader (UEFI x86_64: /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.fd) . Can you explain why for Pavol,here,it worked like a charm ? ---> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnVbbD7G0Bo&t=337s&ab_channel=PavolElsig

Comment: I have seen all kinds of weird bugs and compatibility issues between different versions of qemu and OVMF. I always had best results with builds from the edk2 repository. I am also not sure how he got that to work with q35 emulation, I never managed to get that to work with PCI passthrough. Use the XML from the article above, that should "just work" with minimal changes (PCI IDs, storage paths, firmware paths).

Comment: in the article above there are millions of changes that I could apply,but none of them is sure. It can take forever to find the working combinations. I can't spend my whole life like this.

Comment: You could copy the config file as is and change the paths for disk and firmware locations, along with the PCI device IDs. The reality is that this setup is relevant to maybe 0.1% of qemu / libvirt users. Nobody upstream cares enough to polish the experience down to clicking in a GUI.

Comment: Hey so I don't yet have an answer here but I wanted to jump in and say that I have it mostly working. The problem I have is the PNY Quadro T600 does not have Windows 7 drivers from NVIDIA and hacking my own is not something I can do. Everything else is working correctly. Also I have a Windows 11 Pro VM running under UEFI Q35 with 0 issues. Why is i440FX better than Q35 @GordanBobić? The Win 11 VM is running with no modifications other than E43 on an unmodified Linux Mint install. Also it should be noted that my Win 7 VM is running the modified OVMF firmware and was installed using 2018 iso.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow I am not saying that i440FX is "better", merely that I never managed to get it working for this. It is possible that things have changed since I developed my recipes for it.